# simple requestAnimationFrame not working JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, animation, html5-canvas

I am currently trying to understand animation using JavaScript and HTML5. 
From what I have gathered after researching on the internet, requestAnimationFrame repeatedly calls a method.

I have created a plane, and created a method which will move the plane in a diagonal line. However, it there seems to be no animation.

I'm fairly new to this so it could be just me not quite getting the concept. I don't think it is to do with my browser as I have tried it on both chrome and internet explorer, and they should be up to date as I only installed them a few months ago as this is a new laptop.

Here is my main class, it should include all relevent code:

```
 /*global window, document, alert, Vector, Moth, Matrix, Plane, SceneGraphNode*/
 function onLoad() {
var mainCanvas, mainContext, planePosition, plane;
// this function will initialise our variables


function initialiseCanvasContext() {
    // Find the canvas element using its id attribute.
    mainCanvas = document.getElementById('mainCanvas');
    // if it couldn't be found
    if (!mainCanvas) {
        // make a message box pop up with the error.
        alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!');
        return;
    }
    // Get the 2D canvas context.
    mainContext = mainCanvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!mainContext) {
        alert('Error: failed to get context!');
        return;
    }
    planePosition = new Vector(0, 0, 0);
    plane = new Plane(planePosition);
}


function translate(pPosition) {
    var matrix = Matrix.createTranslation(pPosition);
    matrix.transform(mainContext);
}

function scale(pPosition) {
    var matrix = Matrix.createScale(pPosition);
    matrix.transform(mainContext);
}

function rotate(pPosition) {
    var matrix = Matrix.createRotation(pPosition);
    matrix.transform(mainContext);
}

function drawPlane() {
    scaleVector = new Vector(0.25, 0.25, 0);
    scale(scaleVector);
    translate(new Vector(0, 0));
    rotate(0);
    plane.draw(mainContext);
}

function drawMoth() {
    var moth, mothPosition;
    mothPosition = new Vector(mainCanvas.width / 2, mainCanvas.height / 2, 0);
    moth = new Moth(mothPosition);
    moth.draw(mainContext);
}

function drawPlane() {
    plane = new Plane(planePosition);
    scale(new Vector(0.25, 0.25, 0));
    plane.draw(mainContext);
}

function animatePlane() {
    translate(planePosition.add(new Vector(100, 100, 0)));
    drawPlane();
    window.requestAnimationFrame(animatePlane);
}

initialiseCanvasContext();
drawMoth();
animatePlane();
 }
 window.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false);
```

Please let me know if you think it would help to see any associated methods. I have also attached the result.

[image: The result]

Comment: Please update your question to include all relevant code. When & where are those two functions called?

Comment: Hi, I've updated it now, sorry about that

Comment: Do you have any error on your console?

Comment: @balapa no don't seem to have any

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things are undefined here (the Matrix and Vector objects and their methods). Please include the code if you have it, otherwise keep reading.

**It seems you've got a bit of a gap in your Object-Oriented JS knowledge. I'm guessing you know a good chunk of this, but it will be worth your time to solidify your knowledge of the following:**

- Know how to make a new object. Understand what an object is.
- Understand how to make a constructor function.
- Understand that using the *new* keyword simply calls an object's constructor function.
- Understand inheritance. The *this* keyword vs. prototypical inheritance.
- Understand encapsulation.
- Understand the Canvas API
- Add comments to your code. If other people are going to read you're code, please add comments. It helps. All you really need is a single comment per function explaining what it does. Explaining what the input parameters are is useful to.

**Here are some resources to get you started (and perhaps finished):**

- Read this (and it's two prerequisites): http://javascriptissexy.com/oop-in-javascript-what-you-need-to-know/
- Check out the built-in Canvas methods: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API

**Here are the code structures that were missing**

```js
function Vector(x, y, z) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.z = z;
}

var Matrix = {
  createTranslation: function() {
  
  }, 
    createRotation: function() {
    
  }, 
    createScale: function() {
    
  }, 
  transform: function() {
    
  }
};

function Plane(position) {
  this.add = function() {
  this.draw = function() {
    
  };
  };
}

function Moth(position) {
  this.draw = function() {
    
  };
}
```

I know this doesn't answer your question and I'm likely about to be downvoted to hell, but I can't really help you until you understand what you're doing a bit better. Good luck!